# Burrow Dashboard UI not showing up

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, linkedin-api, monitoring

I have modified Burrow charts available at https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-kafka/tree/master/linkedin-burrow

Things are working fine.

I have port-forwarded my burrow deployment to localhost:8000

When I hit the API endpoints, I am receiving the correct output.

However the Burrow dashboard API is not coming up.

How to get the UI?

Attaching screenshot for reference

[image]

Attaching kubernetes deployment details as well

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a service object that exposes your deployment:

`$ kubectl expose deployment your-deployment --type=LoadBalancer --name=your-service`

Check some information about the Service:

`$ kubectl get services your-service`

The output should be similar to this:

```
NAME             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)    AGE
your-service   LoadBalancer      x.y.a.b       c.d.e.f          8080/TCP   10s
```

If the external IP address is in  status, wait a while and execute the same command again.

To get to Burrow UI you need to define IP and add them to host file (on Linux is **/etc/hosts)**

```
vi /etc/hosts

your_borrow_external_ip www.preffered-name-of-site.com
```

Egg:

```
vi /etc/hosts

10.107.12.12 www.example.com
```

Then use the external IP address (LoadBalancer Ingress) to access the your application:

`http://<external-ip>:<port>`

More information you can find here:   [`exposing-application`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/).

I hope it helps.